# No action when button click

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, android-button

I have `customView` class. this class is one of the `viewPager` views. I want to do all the logic related to controlling `ViewPager` will be in one place: `PagerAdapter`, not in several places.I tried do this, but when I click button - there are no any action.
CustomView class:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Button button;
    private OnClickListener clickListener;
 
    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.button);

        public void setClickListener(OnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
```

adapter class:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;
    private CustomView customView;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        customView = new CustomView(context);

      clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("debug", "works");
            }
        };
    }

    public void setCustomView(CustomView customView) {
        this.customView = customView;
        customView.setClickListener(clickListener);
    }
.........
```

activity:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter;
    private CustomView customView;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       customView = new CustomView(this);
        customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
        customPagerAdapter.setCustomView(customView);

    }
}
```

Comment: Update question with complete **CustomPagerAdapter**.

Answer (score 0):

Move this method outside from your custom view constructor and call it after view creation:

```
    public void setClickListener(OnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
```

Comment: in this case I get exception: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Monica try to create CustomView only in adapter, then create listener with Log, ad then call setClickListener. Don't forget to check button for null

Comment: if I create `CustomView` only in adapter and delete `CustomView` from `Activity`, I get exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.company.example.CustomView.setOnNextButtonClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` line `customView.setOnNextButtonClickListener(onNextButtonClickListener);`